# I used the firebase in my app is it uploadable to play store or not?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I used the firebase database. I want to upload my app into playstore is it possible?
if yes how to upload?

Comment: not sure about firebase , but i think you need a google play developer account , and i know it costs 25$ !

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html

Comment: Of course you can upload your application to the Google Play Store. You will have to view, edit, modify, etc., your Firebase Database and other Firebase Services from the Firebase Console, and you can view app stats and other publishing relating data from the Play Console, or ITunes Connect for IOS. The link given from Renaud Tarnec should suffice for your endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using firebase as a backend doesn't affect whether or not you can upload to play store. You need to have a Google play developer account, sign up here: https://developer.android.com/distribute/console/index.html

In the console you can upload an apk (android app build file)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely upload your app on play store. Having firebase for back-end doesn't effect your app.you just need to have Google play account.